# how to show directory list of server side in android

Tags: android, client-server, directory, file-listing

I want to know is it possible to show directory list of server side in android.
The directory list is just folder/file name with folder icon from server side, actually the server side directory is in linux like  "/home/public/user/abc" or "/home/public/user/a.jgp". User can click the folder/file name in android.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/) the full code for a local file chooser.  You can modify it to interact with your server quite easily.